# Display Files available online in an app React-native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

Now If we want user to view a file for which we have the url we use the google docs in a WebView. But the webview in react-native is not as reliable it won't open certain sites. Is there any workaround to it or better yet a component. [image]

The above is the  output when the load is completed.
In the picture below you can see that the onLoadStart is being called thrice(log : loading) and onLoadEnd is being called without displaying a single pixel *sigh*
[image]

Comment: Have you got any example sites which make it 'unreliable'? As the component utilises native counterparts it'd be interesting to see what sites are affected.

Comment: well for instance I try to open drive.google.com add an onLoadStart function to tell me when the actual load starts and onLoadEnd to tell me when the load ends and the onLoadStart is called 3 times and then onLoadEnds and then nothing and no setState or force update is being called in the meantime I'll post some pictures in the question so that you can have a look

Comment: Does the view load any other web-page normally? i.e. Are you sure you're actually seeing the webview itself?

Comment: I am quite sure I am seeing the webview itself actually I think I found where the problem is, now what happens is I am trying to open a pdf file of a docx file with a given link from google drive now what is happening is I think the file is still being downloaded in the background but the page was already loaded. anyway to find out if I am right?